# Find all the positive divisors of a positive integer

Tags: c#, algorithm, .net, factors

This came from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50656827/find-nonnegative-numbers-in-range-n-k-which-number-of-divisors-is-the-multipl/50658078#50658078) question.

Find all the positive divisors of an integer >= 2.

Can stop when i * i >= number.

Please review for speed and style.

```
public class IntWithDivisors
{
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Number;
    }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if(obj is IntWithDivisors)
        {
            return ((IntWithDivisors)obj).Number == this.Number;
        }
        return false;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"number {Number}    Devisors " + string.Join(", ", Divisors);
    }

    public List<int> Divisors { get; } = new List<int>();
    public int Count { get { return Divisors.Count(); } }
    public int Number { get; }
    public IntWithDivisors(int number)
    {
        if (number < 2)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
        Number = number;
        Divisors = IntDivisors(number);
    }               
}
public static List<int> IntDivisors(int num)
{
    //Debug.WriteLine($"\nIntDevisors  {num}");
    List<int> intDivisors = new List<int>();
    intDivisors.Add(1);
    intDivisors.Add(num);
    int i;
    int incr;
    if(num / 2 * 2 == num)
    {
        i = 2;
        incr = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        i = 3;
        incr = 2;
    }
    for(; i*i < num; i += incr)
    {
        int numOveri = num / i;
        if (numOveri * i == num)
        {
            //Debug.WriteLine(i);
            intDivisors.Add(i);
            intDivisors.Add(numOveri);
        }
    }
    if(i*i == num)
    {
        intDivisors.Add(i);
    }
    intDivisors.Sort();
    return intDivisors;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why is the implementation of the algorithm a static method outside of the class `IntWithDivisors`? Is it in `class Program`? It shouldn't be there.

It is unusual to do complex work in the constructor. A constructor should only perform initialization. See answer of Telastyn in [how complex a constructor should be](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/224065/41596). There are different possibilities to solve this

E.g. lazy evaluation:

```
private List<int> _divisors;
public List<int> Divisors
{
    get {
        if (_divisors == null) {
            _divisors = IntDivisors(Number);
        }
        return _divisors;
    }
}
```

Another option is to simply call a method to get the result.

This leads us to the next question: what is the task of the class `IntWithDivisors`? Do we really need to store the input number together with the output? Do we really need to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`?

I would rather opt for a minimalist but reusable and flexible approach in the LINQ style as extension method implemented as iterator.

I observed that the starting `i` is one bigger than `incr`. We can use this fact to simplify the initialization.

Testing if a number is even is usually done with the modulo operator which yields the remainder of the division `num % 2 == 0`.

`numOveri` is a strange name. I renamed it to `quotient` and `i` to `divisor`.

The divisors are tested in ascending order; however, the quotients accumulate in descending order. Therefore, we can return the divisors immediately with `yield return` and store the quotients in a list. We then need to reverse this list before we return its items.

```
public static class IntExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<int> SelectDivisors(this int num)
    {
        yield return 1;

        int incr = num % 2 == 0 ? 1 : 2;
        var largeDivisors = new List<int>();
        for (int divisor = incr + 1; divisor * divisor <= num; divisor += incr) {
            int quotient = num / divisor;
            if (quotient * divisor == num) {
                yield return divisor;
                if (quotient != divisor) {
                    largeDivisors.Add(quotient);
                }
            }
        }

        largeDivisors.Reverse();
        for (int k = 0; k < largeDivisors.Count; k++) {
            yield return largeDivisors[k];
        }

        yield return num;
    }
}
```

We can use this extension method like this (shown in a little test routine):

```
int[] numbers = new[] { 9, 12, 15, 16, 17, 27, 54 };
foreach (int num in numbers) {
    Console.Write($"Number {num} has divisors ");
    foreach (int n in num.SelectDivisors()) {
        Console.Write(n + " ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  My though on public static List<int> IntDivisors is so that it could be called directly.   You want divisors on a single number.     If a class can define gethashcode and equals then I always implement.  I like the better names.   Quotient is not really a good name.  It is the BigDivisor.  So maybe DivisorSmall and DivisorBig.  In my testing n / i * i was faster then modus.

Comment: I like IntExtensions and the reverse to avoid a sort.

Comment: Well, the quotient can be a divisor or not, depending on whether there is a remainder. But these namings are always a matter of taste. As long as they are understandable, they're all okay.

Comment: Not arguing.  But divisor can also be a divisor or not, depending on whether there is a remainder.   Great feedback.

Answer (score -3):

What I ended up with

```
public static class IntExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<int> SelectDivisors(this int num)
    {
        yield return 1;

        int incr = (num / 2 * 2 == num) ? 1 : 2;
        var largeDivisors = new List<int>();
        for (int smallDivisor = incr + 1; smallDivisor * smallDivisor <= num; smallDivisor += incr)
        {
            int largeDivisor = num / smallDivisor;
            if (largeDivisor * smallDivisor == num)
            {
                yield return smallDivisor;
                if (largeDivisor != smallDivisor)
                {
                    largeDivisors.Add(largeDivisor);
                }
            }
        }

        for (int k = largeDivisors.Count - 1; k >= 0; k--)
        {
            yield return largeDivisors[k];
        }

        yield return num;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would posting what I ended up with get down votes?

Comment: Self answers should be answers as well. This is just a code dump without a review of the code. If you can't add anything new you should refuse self-answers and better ask a follow-up question.

Comment: @paparazzo "_If you want to show everyone how you improved your code, but don't want to ask another question, then post an answer to your own question_"... But remember: "_Your answer must meet the standards of a Code Review answer, just like any other answer. **Describe what you changed, and why.**" - from the section _I improved my code based on the reviews. What next?_ on [Help Center > Asking > _What should I do when someone answers my question?_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)